# Excel lookup list of date in sheet,

Tags: excel, excel-match

I have 2 sheet in excel and Second sheet have list of date. We need to lookup all the list of date and compare than today() date. Take first greater than date and get the same row another column.
Tried below this,

```
=MATCH(MIN(IF(Sheet3!B2:B67>TODAY(),"",FALSE)),Sheet3!G2:G67,-1)
```

Comment: Try `=XLOOKUP(TODAY(),Sheet3!$B$1:$B$15,Sheet3!$C$1:$C$15,,1)`

Comment: So, did it worked for your case?

Comment: Yes it was worked

Comment: I have posted as answer so that you can accept it (tick mark it) to treat the question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula

```
 =XLOOKUP(TODAY(),Sheet3!$B$1:$B$15,Sheet3!$C$1:$C$15,,1)
```